# nginx and monit web interface - how to have monit on domain.com/monit versus domain.com

Tags: nginx, monit

I am using monit on my ec2 instance and I am new to nginx.  Below is my nginx config file:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name 127.0.0.1;
  location / {
    proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:2812;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
  }
}
```

So..if I go to domain.com I see monit.  How do I modify above code where I can see monit on domain.com/monit?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please, try this:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name 127.0.0.1;

  location /monit/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2812;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
  }

}
```

Please,  read more [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) about how directive location works in nginx

Comment: Am I supposed to create the directory /usr/local/nginx/html/monit?

Comment: if I dont add a dir I get this error when I run etc/init.d/nginx Starting nginx: nginx: [emerg] invalid URL prefix in /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:61

Comment: This only worked for me when I put a trailing forward-slash (`/`) in the URI for `proxy_pass` like so: `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2812/;`

Comment: @DimitrySandalov's answer should also be included in this answer.

Comment: However this seem weird if monit is setup to keep nginx up

Answer (score 4):

There's an article in Monit's [wiki](http://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/Nginx) how to configure it with Nginx.

Here's my `/etc/nginx/conf.d/monit.conf`:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name  my.server.name;

    location /monit/ {
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            allow 192.0.0.0/8;
            deny all;

            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2812;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            rewrite ^/monit/(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_ignore_client_abort on;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sergei already correctly answered your direct question. I think it's also worth noting that this may be cleaner to just use a subdomain:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name monit.domain.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:2812;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
  }
}
```